# Powershell start-process from Jenkins pipeline with -RedirectStandardOutput does not output

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

When running powershell start-process from Jenkins pipeline with -RedirectStandardOutput "$PSScriptRoot\Script.output.txt"
locally it writes the output to the file.
When it runs in my jenkins pipeline i does not out anything to "$PSScriptRoot\Script.output.txt"

The pipeline runs on a windows node  calls the script like this

```
stage("RunPowershellWith AnotherUser")
    
    {
        steps
        {
            script 
            {
                withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'c7e30cd4-4b6f-4387-8b2d-59f095bb5aae', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']])  {
                    powershell "${workspace}\\startAS.ps1 ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD} "
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The startAS.ps1 executes another powershell script with other credentials. The $PSScriptRoot\Script.output.txt is created, but there are no data in it. In fact i am in doubt if it is executed at all.

The powershell script looks like this

```
    Param
    (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Please provide username")][string] $username
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Please provide password")][string] $password 
    
    )

  
     Write-Host "Running startAS"

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

    Start-process C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
  "$PSScriptRoot\update_gdpr_module_dt_tables.ps1" -Credential $credential  -WorkingDirectory "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"  -RedirectStandardError "$PSScriptRoot\Script.output.error.txt" -RedirectStandardOutput "$PSScriptRoot\Script.output.txt"
```

It Runs fine from my locale workstation

Comment: Maybe you could use Jenkins itself to get the script output like [this](https://automationscript.com/how-to-read-console-output-in-jenkins-pipeline/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code did not even execute the script. My problem was to execute a powershell withcredentials from another user.
I figured it out with this example

```
stage('run powershell with credentials from jenkins') {
    steps {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'c7e30cd4-4b6f-4387-8b2d-59f095bb5aae', passwordVariable: 'passVar', usernameVariable: 'userVar')]) {
            powershell '''
                & .\\myscript.ps1
            '''
        }
        
    }
}
```